# MutableStateFlow for methods

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-stateflow

I’m trying to make my methods reactive to update the view in Compose. How to do it properly?

```
interface Foo{
  val a: Int
  fun bar(): Int
  fun foo(): MutableStateFlow<Int> = MutableStateFlow(bar() * a)
}

//@Composable
val foo by fooImpl.foo().collectAsState()
```

P.S. Currently I made a hack: empty usage a variable `a` participated in calculations. But it’s not good.

```
val a = fooImpl.collectAsState()
a
```

Comment: Why do it at all?

Comment: Because of calculations in models. It's not always done on a server side.

Comment: I still don't understand your problem. There are many different ways run something. Why is it necessary `fun ...: MutableStateFlow<Int>`? I don't know situations where this might be needed instead of other approaches

Comment: Ok, the simple question is: how to make an observable function?

Comment: I suppose, the best but longest way is to observe all variables participated in the method and then provide a final observable variable. But it doesn't work in interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it - subscribe to all variables used in a method.

```
var a = MutableStateFlow(0)
fun bar() = a.value +1
fun chad() = 42
fun foo() = bar() * chad()

val foo: Flow
  get() = a.map { (it + 1) * chad() }

fun useFoo() = runBlocking {
    withContext {
        foo.collect {
            something(it)
        }
    }
}
```